# Как синхронизировать drag'n'drop и обычное добавление файла?

Tags: javascript, fileupload, drag-n-drop

Имеется такой код:

```js
function StyleInput(options) {
  this.inputsFile = document.querySelector(options.targetInputsSelector);
  this.elementOutputPath = options.elementToOutputSeelector;
  this.classToCloseButton = options.classToCloseButton;
  this.selectorToCloseButton = options.selectorToCloseButton;
  this.dropArea = document.querySelector(options.dropArea);
  this.data = [];



  var self = this;

  this.changePath = function() {
    
    filePath = self.data[0].name;
    var output = self.inputsFile.parentNode.querySelector(self.elementOutputPath);
    if(self.checkfile(filePath)) {
      output.innerHTML = filePath + '<div class="'+ self.classToCloseButton + '"> </div> ';
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = '.pdf';
      self.inputsFile.value = ''; 
    }

    var closeButton = document.querySelector(self.selectorToCloseButton);
    if(closeButton) {
      closeButton.onclick = function() {
        self.deleteFile()
      }
    }
    
  }


 


  this.checkfile = function(filepath) {
    if (filepath.indexOf('rar', filepath.lastIndexOf('.')+1) > -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }


  this.addFile = function() {

        //Drag and drop

        var eventsDrop = ['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop',];


        function preventDefaults (e) {
          e.preventDefault()
          e.stopPropagation()
        }
      
        for(var i = 0; i < eventsDrop.length; i++) {
          self.dropArea.addEventListener(eventsDrop[i], preventDefaults)
        }
      
        
      
      
        var eventsEnter = ['dragenter', 'dragover'];

        function highlight(e) {
          self.dropArea.classList.add('highlight')
          console.log(1)
        }
      
        for(var i = 0; i < eventsEnter.length; i++) {
          self.dropArea.addEventListener(eventsEnter[i], highlight)
        }
      
        
      
        var eventsLeave = ['dragleave', 'drop',];

        function unhighlight(e) {
          self.dropArea.classList.remove('highlight')
        }
        
        for(var i = 0; i < eventsLeave.length; i++) {
          self.dropArea.addEventListener(eventsLeave[i], unhighlight)
        }

        self.dropArea.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
          self.data = e.dataTransfer.files;
          self.changePath()
        })
      

        self.inputsFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
          self.data = self.inputsFile.files;
          self.changePath()
        });
  }

  this.deleteFile = function() {
     self.inputsFile.value = '';
     console.log(self.inputsFile.files)

     var output = self.inputsFile.parentNode.querySelector(self.elementOutputPath);
      output.innerHTML = '.pdf';
  }

  this.addFile();
}

new StyleInput({
  dropArea: '#drop-area',
  targetInputsSelector: '#fileElem',
  elementToOutputSeelector: '.fake-fileload-label',
  classToCloseButton: 'fake-fileload-icon',
  selectorToCloseButton: '.fake-fileload-icon'
})
```

Суть в том, что я не могу синхронизировать добавление файла при помощи drag'n'drop и добавление файла при помощи кнопки. Потому что когда происходит добавление при помощи кнопки, файлы идут в `input.files`, а когда при помощи дропа, то в `e.dataTransfer.files`

Я пробовал менять сам массив `input.files` при дропе, но это невозможно из-за безопасности. Пробовал создать свой массив, но опять же, я не могу прописать свой `value` в `input` из-за безопасности. Мои идеи закончились. Не могу отправлять ajax'ом это, потому что там идет еще и отправка других полей. Есть ли вариант сделать это без ajax?

Comment: возможно присваивать лишь целиком `input[type="file"].files = dataTransfer.files`

Comment: Если честно, ничего не понятно. Что вы хотите в итоге сделать? Почему не можете отправить через `AJAX`?